# Form action html to php

Tags: php, html

i have

```
<form action = "https://creator.zoho.com/api/xml/fileupload/scope=creatorapi&authtoken=**************" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">                     
    <input type="text" name="applinkname" value="sample">
    <input type="text" name="formname" value="Employee">
    <input type="text" name="fieldname" value="File_upload">

    <input type="text" name="recordId" value="1235667754455">
    <input type="text" name="filename" value="profile.jpg" >
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

But i must send 2500 files, how can i transform this html to php, my problem is `<input type="file" name="file">`, how convert it to give a value in php ?

thanks you

Comment: Take a look at phps `cURL` extension: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php It allows to make http post requests as you need to and comes with good examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_REQUEST['FILE']=$SOME VARIABLE`;
And name is same what you use in your database
then apply `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.